# ASP.NET C# SITE similar to grubhub and Seamless. Need restaurants to confirm received orders by entering a code by phone.

Tags: c#, asp.net

Thanks for taking the time to help me. We're building similar site like Delivery.com, grubhub and seamless.com. Customers order food from restaurants. Restaurants receive orders by email and fax. They call our phone number, enter a code and that confirms that the order was received successfully by them. What do I need to register that confirmation on the backend in my db to show that the order has been confirmed? I am not a tech person as you can tell. Is Twilio a valid option? using their api with a WPF, can they call, enter the code and that will be converted into some script on our server to register the confirmation? if not, any other services or scripts I need to build?

Comment: I think there's a jQuery plugin for this.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I've used that one. `$.fax(await phone);`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Devin gave me a detailed answer. Called Twilio and they confirmed that I can implement my solution using their API.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can totally use Twilio to do this.  Do do this I'd suggest [creating a new Twilio account](https://www.twilio.com/try-twilio?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) (its free to try) and walking through the [Handle Incoming Calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/twiml?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) quickstart.  That will give you a great foundation for understanding the basic Twilio concepts like TwiML and WebHooks.

As part of the quickstart you'll need to stand up some kind of web endpoint on your server that Twilio can make HTTP requests to, so that could be something like an ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET WebForms site.

Once you've worked through the quickstart, to build your application you are going to need to use the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) verb which tells Twilio to start listening for the caller to enter tones.  Once they have entered the tones Twilio will pass those to your application as a [request parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action-parameters?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) (in this called Digits), and your application can use that data to run whatever kind of application logic you want.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that helped and answered my question. Thanks Devin.